# How to extract ephemeral and static private keys from ecc private key using openssl

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

I am using the following openssl command to generate an ECC key for SECp384:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out private.pem
```

Can someone please let me know how to extract ephemeral(k) and static(k) private keys from generated ecc private key using openssl?

In the link https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4754.txt these are mentioned as `w` and `k`.

Answer (score 0):

An ephemeral key is a key you generate, use, then throw away.

A static key is a key you use for a long time, perhaps by putting it into an X.509 Public Key Certificate.

Each of those are concept words, and behind the concept would be an ECC key like the one you generated.

```
        key
       /   \
static       ephemeral
   |             |
 cert          keyGenerator
   |
 getAssociatedKey
```